Nerve theorem and cycles deformation
Consider a finite set of point $P\subset[0,1]^{d}$. Let $r>0$, by nerve theorem, we know that, the Čech complex $C^{2r}(P)$ and $B_{2}(P,r)$ are homotopy equivalent.
Furthermore, Proposition 3.2 of "Approximating Cycles in a Shortest Basis of the First Homology
Group from Point Data" by T. Dey, J. Sun and Y. Wang (https://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~dey.8/paper/pcdloop/pcdloop.pdf), shows that we can construct a homotopy equivalence $f:C^{2r}(P)\rightarrow B_{2}(P,r)$, such that for each simplex $\sigma \in C^{2 r}(P)$, $f(\sigma) \subset \cup_{p \in \operatorname{Vert}(\sigma)} B(p, r)$ and $f(p)=p$ for any $p \in P$.
Denote $i_{s}:H_{s}(C^{2r}(P))\rightarrow H_{s}(B_{2}(P,r))$ the associated isomorphism between (degree $s$) homology groups. If i am not mistaken, this implies that for a cycle $C\in C_{s}(C^{2r}(P))$, there exists $C^{'}\in C_{s}(B_{2}(P,r))$ such that $[C^{'}]=i_{s}([C])$ (with $[C]$ the homology classes of $C$ in $H_{s}(C^{2r}(P))$ and $[C^{'}]$ the homology classes of $C^{'}$ in $H_{s}(C^{2r}(P))$) and $d_{H}(C,C^{'})\leq 2r$ ($d_{h}$ being the Hausdorff distance).
I wonder if, conversely, for any $C\in C_{s}(B_{2}(P,r))$, there exists $C^{'}\in C_{s}(C^{2r}(P))$, such that  $[C^{'}]=i_{s}^{-1}([C])$ and $d_{H}(C,C^{'})\leq 2r$ ?
Edit : To clarify my question (and to be closer to the result I cite), It can be somehow reformulated into : is there a homotopy equivalence $g: B_{2}(P,r)\rightarrow C^{2r}(P)$ such that for all $x\in B_{2}(P,r)$, $g(x)\in B_{2}(x,2r)$ ? (or similar control on $g(x)$)
